# Can I disable italics in the body text of a theorem without amsthm/ntheorem?

Tags: fonts, environments, theorems, document-classes

I'm submitting a paper and am required to use a provided document class which defines its own theorem environments, so I can't use packages like `amsthm` or `ntheorem`. The class doesn't define a 'Definition' theorem environment, so I defined my own. I'm trying to get the body text not to be in italic, just like `\theoremstyle{definition}` does. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: What does the current definition of your `definition` environment look like? Edit your question and include this detail.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). As Werner suggests, It is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages. In this case the problem is related to your specific definition so without that it is difficult to help.

Comment: Werner, your answer will do. I don't have so many definitions that it's inconvenient for me to use this ad-hoc trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Ad-hoc restyling can be done using `\normalfont` at the start of the `definition`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\begin{document}
\begin{definition}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
Sed eu eros dignissim mi ultricies varius in ac purus. 
Mauris et massa turpis. Aenean egestas fringilla odio, 
in placerat leo vestibulum non.
\end{definition}

\begin{definition}
\normalfont Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
Sed eu eros dignissim mi ultricies varius in ac purus. 
Mauris et massa turpis. Aenean egestas fringilla odio, 
in placerat leo vestibulum non.
\end{definition}
\end{document}
```

The above solution would hold for journals where you're not allowed to include other packages. If they don't mind and your `definition` theorem environment is defined very simply, you could use something like:

```
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\let\olddefinition\definition
\renewcommand{\definition}{\olddefinition\normalfont}
```

to modify the start of the environment to *always* use `\normalfont`. This would then be a global change to the `definition` theorem environment. Of course, you need not use a theorem-style to create the `definition` environment in the first place. However, without much knowledge over the context and use, it would be hard to speculate on how you want it to look.

The above redefinition doesn't allow the use of an optional argument for the `definition` environment. If you want this, you can use

```
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}

\usepackage{xparse}
\let\olddefinition\definition
\RenewDocumentCommand{\definition}{o}{%
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}
    {\olddefinition}
    {\olddefinition[#1]}%
  \normalfont
}
```

instead. The above uses [`xparse`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xparse) to capture and examine the possibility of an optional argument, and using it if it exists, before inserting the `\normalfont` override.

Comment: `\upshape` is another possibility.

Comment: But your answer doesn't work if some of your `definition` environments have optional arguments (e.g., `\begin{definition}[nonrigorous]`), does it?

Comment: @MSC: True. In those instances you'll have to capture the optional argument first, then process it before inserting `\normalfont`. I've added that to the answer. You could do something more hack-y, but [`xparse`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xparse) allows for a clean interpretation of the optional argument.